# How do I get SemanticMerge to recognize C++?

Tags: c++, semantic-merge

According to the documentation Semanticmerge supports C++ natively.

But when I run it on a set of files (from TortoiseHg), despite the fact that they have a .cpp extension, it thinks they are C#. This of course messes up the language parsing and completely negates the whole point of the tool!

I can't see any settings for file associations, or a manual override for the current merge.

Answer (score 1):

Lunch the `SemanticMergeTool.exe` with `-l=cpp` switch 
For a complete set of options run `SemanticMergeTool.exe -?`

Comment: The question asker wanted SemanticMerge to treat the files as C++, not C# (which is what it was already doing, incorrectly), although this is in the right direction.

Comment: Edited my answer following @Hasturkun remark